# Copying unique string from one list to another list from text file

Tags: c++, c++14

I've been asked to make a list of data from a text file of words which is equal to a specific length of letters, the user inputs the length wanted and the function would make a list of all the words that have the same length. I tried making it with a list but changed to a vector but I still couldn't manage to make it work. I've been able to load all of the words in the text file into a vector (and also when it was a list) but only inserting the words of a given length caused issues and no words were entered into the vector. Would a map be better?

```cpp
    vector<string> wordListA;
    vector<string> wordListB;
    int count = 0;
    myfile.open(filename); // opening the filename given in command line
    if (myfile.is_open()) //testing if the file is opened or not
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            string newline;
            newline = line;
            wordListA.push_back(newline);
        }
        vector<string>::const_iterator it;
        it = wordListA.begin();
        for (it; it != wordListA.end(); it++)
        {
            string c = *it;
            if (c.length() == wordLength + 1)
            {
                wordListB.push_back(c);
                count++;
            }
        }
        cout << count << endl;

    }
  else
    {
        cout << "Error when opening file: " << filename << endl;
    }
  myfile.close();
}
```

I think my method for finding the length is wrong. I tried 4 different methods and none worked! I do think I need to be using a list data structure and not a vector.
previously I tried this which also didn't seem to work:

```cpp
        string newline;
        newline= line; //load current line into nl

        if (int(newline.length()) == wordLength + 1)
        {
            wordListA.push_back(newline); //append into list
        }
```

Updated but still doesnt work:

```
while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            string newline;
            newline = line;
            if (int(newline.length()) == wordlength)
            {
                wordListA.push_back(newline);
                unique++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
        vector<string> wordListA;
        int wordLength=3;
        string filename;
        string line;

        cin>>filename;

        ifstream myfile;

        myfile.open(filename); // opening the filename given in command line
        if (myfile.is_open()) //testing if the file is opened or not
        {
                while (getline(myfile, line))
                {
                        if(line.length()==wordLength)
                                wordListA.push_back(line);
                }
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "Error when opening file: " << filename << endl;
        }
        myfile.close();
        
        //print vector of strings
        for(auto i:wordListA)
                cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. wordLength + 1 is not required, its just enough to check if c.length()==wordLength
2. Also maintaining 2 vector may not be required, as the file is read with getline(), each string length can be checked against the wordLength and then only push_back
3. when inserting at the end many times, vector is better than list considering the time complexity

Comment: what do you mean its not required? Im looking for a way to make a list of strings of a given length, for example, all words that have a length of 4 will go into listB

Comment: My issue is that the words dont go into of listB at all

Comment: for example, If you want to insert words of length 5, then its enough to check c.length()==wordLength; as c.length() will give 5, if the word has 5 chars

Comment: Originally, @lorenz, I had the length checking done while the lines were being read but since It didn't work I focused on just reading all the words in and then to try and solve my length issue. Ive changed my data strcs to lists but still cant get it to enter only strings of a given length!

Comment: I removed +1 from your condition check, if (c.length() == wordLength + 1), and executed your original code, it worked. what did this line print after you remove "+1" ? ```cout << count << endl;```

Comment: @verticallypickled I have added another answer for your understanding, (cleaned the code to remove the clutter)  Please check and accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: my count always gave to output 0 which is why I thought there was an issue. I ended up redoing the code formate and testing the code in different areas for output to see where I was going wrong. It works now! not sure what caused the issue my mate thinks my compiler was broken so I reinstalled it, but I think that's unlikely. Anyhow it works! thank you for your time and effort :)

Comment: @verticallypickled Since it worked for you, please make my answer "accepted answer" in stackoverflow. That gives me some points on my account. Also you can upvote. Thanks.